# xcode show all errors in all source code files?

Tags: ios, xcode, compiler-construction

I am doing some transplant work for my project,there are a lot of issues for me to fix.
Howerer ,when I build the target, not all issues are shown. Many issues in some source code file are not catched by the Xcode.

Maybe the compiler just stoped when too many issued are founded.
Is there any way to make the Xcode to show all errors in all source code files?

[image: iOS 7 music app tabbar management]

many thanks!

Comment: Xcode stops at 200 errors IIRC. I never found a way to increase the limit.

Comment: Or something like gcc opion "-fsyntax-only",  I do not know how to do it in LLVM.

Comment: Two things (besides the 200 limit):  1) There is a setting somewhere that is, in effect, "stop on first error".  2) It is fairly easy to accidentally type a few characters into the search bar at the bottom of the error list, causing only a subset of the messages to display.  Characters typed there are remembered, even if you shut down and restart Xcode.

Comment: It doesn't always make sense to show "all errors". Imagine you forgot one `}` and the rest of the code below is therefore syntactically wrong. All those errors after the first wouldn't mean anything.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is an upper limit to the number of warnings and errors that Xcode will display. I inherited a project that would say "999+ errors" "to many errors" or something similar to that and would finally show the next set when I had brought it down to < 999 errors.

Comment: In fact ,now the Xcode show just 29 issues in my project. I think the compiler just stoped afer some serious issues are founded.  While some  other source code file are nerver compiled,which also contains obviously syntax error.